# IE input different behavior selected text or not

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, input

i found really strange behavior of text input in IE.
I want to change cursor upon form submit, which can be done by hitting enter key.

```
/* IE hack for on enter submit */
$('input').live('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).parents('form').find(".submit").trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});
```

As IE change cursor after move i have to hack it with assigning all elements on page special class with cursor:progress; making it work immediately.

```
$("form.ajax").live("submit", function () {
    $("#load_dialog").show(); /show loading dialog
    if($.browser.msie){ /IE hack
        $("*").addClass("waiting"); /assign class with loading cursor
    }
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); /submit a form
    return false;
});
```

This works great, but with one strange issue.
When i click input (select text) and hit enter without changing text, loading cursor appears (repeatedly), but when i edit text and then hit enter, cursor do not change.

Don't you have any ideas why?

Comment: Not an answer to your Q, but would `$(document).addClass("waiting");` work?  A lot better than attaching a class to every single element in your page

Answer (score 1):

I would change this:

```
$('input').live('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).parents('form').find(".submit").trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});
```

to this:

```
$('input').live('keydown', function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key === 13) {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or, if you're using jQuery 1.7, then `on` should be preferred to `live`, since the latter is deprecated and inefficient

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key === 13) {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

And for pre-1.7 `delegate` is the next best thing:

```
$(document).delegate('input', 'keydown', function(e){
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, i am smarter now, but the problem is not solved. To be clear...even in my original code, submit of the form is fired correctly (form is ajaxed and i can see it in console and also i can see updated areas that are affected by the operation). The problem seems to be in the second part where i change the class. But have no idea how editing of text input could make the behavior different.

Comment: Decided to quit working with cursor and make loadng state by layer with image...seems IE works with cursor change really weird. Thank you Adam for help anyway.